# how to pass extra parameters in to_csv method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**Controller**

```
format.csv { send_data @find_customer.to_csv, :filename => "customer" + ".csv" }
format.xls { send_data @find_customer.to_csv(col_sep: "\t"), filename: 'customer.xls'}
```

**Model**

```
  def self.to_csv(options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv << ["SHW#", "LeadId", "Fullname", "Address", "City", "State", "Zip", "Phone", "Email", "Created-At"]
      all.each do |customer|
        csv << [customer.id, customer.leadid, "#{customer.first_name} #{customer.last_name}", customer.customer_address, customer.customer_city, customer.customer_state, customer.customer_zip, customer.customer_phone, customer.email, customer.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")] 
      end
    end
  end
```

How to pass extra parameters in to_csv method. I want to pass start_date and end_date in to_csv method so How can I ?

**Update 1**

If I pass

format.xls { send_data @find_customer.to_csv(col_sep: "\t", :start_date => "date"), filename: 'customer.xls'}

Then getting error like : Unknown option start_date

Comment: So what's the problem? Put that parameters into the array on 5th line.

Comment: give me example, self.to_csv(options = {}), Here I want to get values from controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
format.csv { send_data @find_customer.to_csv({}, '2014-05-08', '2014-05-10'), :filename => "customer" + ".csv" }
```

model

```
def self.to_csv(options = {}, start_date = '', end_date = '')
  CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
    csv << ["SHW#", "LeadId", "Fullname", "Address", "City", "State", "Zip", "Phone", "Email", "Created-At", "Start", "End"]
    all.each do |customer|
      csv << [customer.id, customer.leadid, "#{customer.first_name} #{customer.last_name}", customer.customer_address, customer.customer_city, customer.customer_state, customer.customer_zip, customer.customer_phone, customer.email, customer.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), start_date, end_date] 
    end
  end
end
```